# Insert a List Into Room Database Using RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2

I have a list of Items I want to map and then insert into a Room table:

Room

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(vararg projectLocal: ProjectLocal): Completable
```

The **FIRST** approach to save data:

```
Observable.fromIterable(remoteProjects)
            .map { project ->
                ...
                mProjectMapper.mapRemoteToLocal(project)
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe {
                mProjectRepository.saveProject(it)
            }
```

As you may see I'm `observing on -> main thread` and `subscribing on -> io`

The **Second** approach to save data:

```
remoteProjects.forEach { remote ->
                ...
                val project = mProjectMapper.mapRemoteToLocal(remote)
                mProjectRepository.saveProject(project)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe()
            }
```

Which one makes more sense? Is there any better way to save all this data inside a Room database using RxJava?

Comment: I think the first approach is better since you're calling the **saveProject()** only once, whereas in the second approach you will end up calling **saveProject()** n times. Also if you don't need to do anything on the UI after adding the items to the database, there is no need to observe it on the main thread, therefore you can delete the **.observeOn()** line.

Comment: @Mwasz Thanks for sharing your opinion It gave me an idea. The first one still calls `saveProject` function multiple times unless I use `Observable.just()` instead of `Observable.fromIterable`

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. An easy solution for that would be calling `.toList()` after mapping and change the `saveProject()` method to accept a ``List<ProjectLocal>``. That way you will call `saveProject()` once for the whole list.

Comment: @Mwasz Post an answer with your logic implemented and I will accept it gladly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what @Mwasz means:

```
Observable.fromIterable(remoteProjects)
        .map { project ->
            mProjectMapper.mapRemoteToLocal(project)
        }
        .toList()
        .flatMapCompletable {
            mProjectRepository.saveProject(it)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        }
        .subscribe()
```

You could also use `reduce` or `collect` instead of `toList` but `toList()` is the simplest.

Comment: I will check this tomorrow and will accept you as the correct answer if it worked ;)